# Почему при выводе пропадает назначенный класс?

Tags: вывод, строки, php

Доброй ночи, бодрствующим!
Выручайте плиз :) Вывожу рекурсией дерево:

```
$ul =  "<ul>\n";
foreach( $tree as &$item ){
    if ( $item['parent'] == 0 ) {
    $ul .=  "<li>\n <p class = sidebar-content-title>".$item['title']."<span class='pull-right icon awe-chevron-down'></span></p> \n </li> \n";
    }
    else {

    $ul .=  "<li> \n <a class = sidebar-link href='".$item['title_en']."'>".$item['title']."</a> \n </li> \n";
    }

    if( ! empty($item['subitems']) )
        $ul .= showTree( $item['subitems'] );
}
$ul .=  "</ul>";
return $ul;
```

Категории (class = sidebar-content-title>) выводятся как следует, а у под-категорий (class = sidebar-link) при выводе пропадает назначаемый им класс %) да и "\n" не переносит строки ... что за хрень такая?

Comment: Кавычки для класса поставьте ('). Не все браузеры умеют распарсить по человечески, то, что вы выводите.

А \n должна работать. У вас же и в коде стояд **двойные** кавычки или только тут?

Comment: Стояли они (кавычки), убрал думал может поможет... уже голова от них кругом. А строки конечно в двойных... какой код есть тот и выложил.
Кстати, опять их нарисовал - не помогло. Смотрю в фаерфоксе и хроме.

Comment: а вообще что нить меняется ? может вы не тот файл правите ?

Comment: Да нет, работаю именно с ним. Для полноты картины, кусок выводимого кода:

<ul>
<li>
 <p class = 'sidebar-content-title'>Раздел 1<span class='pull-right icon awe-chevron-down'></span></p> 
 </li> 
<ul><li><a href="subCategory1.1">Под раздел 1.1</a></li><li><a href="subCategory1.2">Под раздел 1.2</a></li><li><a href="subCategory1.3">Под раздел 1.3</a></li><li><a href="subCategory1.4">Под раздел 1.4</a></li></ul><li>
 <p class = 'sidebar-content-title'>Раздел 2<span class='pull-right icon awe-chevron-down'></span></p> 
 </li>

Comment: По вашему коду, а почему у вас внутренний UL находится вне LI?

Должно быть:

   <ul>
     <li> Text
        <ul>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>

Comment: Потому, что список многоуровневый... т.е. внутренний "ul" определяет вложенный список.

Comment: @SilverIce имел ввиду то что ul в ul нельзя вставлять.

Comment: я потом понял, что Вы имели ввиду, переделал вывод но положительного результата нет... Что именно удивляет - почему отсутствует в результатирующем HTML передаваемый класс:
<a href="subCategory1.3">Под раздел 1.3</a>

хотя ведь передаю ему строку такого вида:
<a class='sidebar-link' href='".$item['title_en']."'>